# SwiftUI, how to translate Text with timer style?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

We are trying to create a iOS 14 widget, due to limitations in the API we are not able to use timers, however we discovered we can use a Text with a Date style that updates itself, however there is very little documentation available and the text does not seem to adjust itself to the phone language.

from the Xcode internal interfaces:

```swift
@available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
extension Text {

    /// A predefined style used to display a `Date`.
    public struct DateStyle {

        /// A style displaying only the time component for a date.
        ///
        ///     Text(event.startDate, style: .time)
        ///
        /// Example output:
        ///     11:23PM
        public static let time: Text.DateStyle

        /// A style displaying a date.
        ///
        ///     Text(event.startDate, style: .date)
        ///
        /// Example output:
        ///     June 3, 2019
        public static let date: Text.DateStyle

        /// A style displaying a date as relative to now.
        ///
        ///     Text(event.startDate, style: .relative)
        ///
        /// Example output:
        ///     2 hours, 23 minutes
        ///     1 year, 1 month
        public static let relative: Text.DateStyle

        /// A style displaying a date as offset from now.
        ///
        ///     Text(event.startDate, style: .offset)
        ///
        /// Example output:
        ///     +2 hours
        ///     -3 months
        public static let offset: Text.DateStyle

        /// A style displaying a date as timer counting from now.
        ///
        ///     Text(event.startDate, style: .timer)
        ///
        /// Example output:
        ///    2:32
        ///    36:59:01
        public static let timer: Text.DateStyle
    }

    /// Creates an instance that displays localized dates and times using a specific style.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - date: The target date to display.
    ///     - style: The style used when displaying a date.
    public init(_ date: Date, style: Text.DateStyle)

    /// Creates an instance that displays a localized range between two dates.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - dates: The range of dates to display
    public init(_ dates: ClosedRange<Date>)

    /// Creates an instance that displays a localized time interval.
    ///
    ///     Text(DateInterval(start: event.startDate, duration: event.duration))
    ///
    /// Example output:
    ///     9:30AM - 3:30PM
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - interval: The date interval to display
    public init(_ interval: DateInterval)
}
```

our code:

```swift
Text(entry.end!, style: .relative)
```

Renders:

[image: iOS image of widget]

We need this text to be adjusted to phone locale (German in the screenshot case), has anyone achieved this?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to localize the .relative time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry about localization, on the simulator it takes the macOS language configuration, but on device it takes the device language.

Comment: The answer is still the same, no need to do anything, it localizes itself